# How to rewrite react mixins in React es6?

Tags: reactjs

Good afternoon, I am trying to transfer the project from React es5 to React es6, and I ran into a problem, namely with mixins.
I have a component of this type.

```
var BasicProfileComponent = React.createClass({

    mixins: [GoogleMapApi],

    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.initializeGoogleMapApi(this.onGoogleApiLoaded);
    }
)}
```

and mixin to it

```
var GoogleMapApi = {
  initializeGoogleMapApi: function(callback) {
    if (window.apiLoaded) {
      callback();
    }

    // adding calback to a queue
    this.pullOfCallbacks.push(callback);
  }
}
```

How can I rewrite this component to React.Component and use mixins inside it or how to make an alternative entry for this mixin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixins aren't used in react for a [loong time now](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html). [High Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) are all valid alternatives to share state logic, and they all work way better than mixins.